# Read basePath in Next.js AppRouter

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next.js13

How can I read `basePath` in Next.js 13 when I use `AppRouter`?

We can get it by reading `router.basePath` from `useRouter` of `PageRouter` by importing `import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

I cannot find any way to read it when I use `AppRouter`

`import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'` has no `basePath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`basePath` has been removed from the `useRouter` hook, as explained in the [App Router Migration Guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#step-5-migrating-routing-hooks). There is currently no replacement.

An alternative would be to use the `env` field in `next.config.js`:

```js
const basePath = process.env.BASE_PATH ?? '' // get `basePath` for your use-case

const nextConfig = {
  basePath,
  env: {
    basePath,
  },
}
```

Then simply use `process.env.basePath` anywhere in the code to access it.